# Clip FrameLayout contents to background drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have a `FrameLayout` which contains a `LinearLayout` with a `TextView` and 2 `View`s with different background colors. The `FrameLayout` has a background drawable which is a rounded light yellow rectangle.

I want the last `View` (the darker yellow one) to be clipped by the background drawable, i.e there should be rounded corners at the bottom of the `FrameLayout`.

How can this be achieved? Can it be done via XML only?

Image to illustrate the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `CardView` with `app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#FFA737"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make different XML and apply to framelayout. XML code is following.

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corner
        android:bottomLeftRadius="Any integer value"
        android:bottomRightRadius="Any integer value" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I intend to make a scrollable list, so the list contents should be clipped to the corners as well.